# Spot-Futures arbitrage profit calculation

Tags: arbitrage

My question is about spot-futures arbitrage.

Lets say, t=0 , Spot Price=1.38 , ArbFree Theoretical Fwd Price= 1.40 and Real Futures Market Price = 1.38. So we see that there's arbitrage. I take a long position on the Futures at 1.38 price, a short position on the spot at 1.38 price, and capture the arbitrage.

And let's say at the t=T , Spot Price=1.38, ArbFree Theoretical Fwd Price= 1.38 (since at t=T, the spot-futures prices converged at maturity), Real Futures Market Price = 1.38. There's no arbitrage. I take a long position on the spot and a short position on the futures and close the positions that I took at t=0.

I calculate the profit (1.38-1.38) + (1.38-1.38) = 0. Am I wrong in the profit calculation?
If the profit calculation is correct, then where is the arbitrage that I captured at t=0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you sold the spot at 1.38 you could (theoretically) have invested the cash you received at the short term interest rate, which we know is positive since the theoretical fwd price is 1.40>1.38. So you would have made some interest in the meantime, which you could consider a profit.

Comment: @noob2 I see, thanks